# How to add Postback button to the Update Panel

Tags: ajax, updatepanel, autopostback

I must add a Post Back Button to refresh all site to the Update Panel. How Could I do it ?

This is my code ASPX:

`<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1"  UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<tr><td style="border: 1px solid #676767; width:200px;"><span style="color:#FF0000; font-weight:bold;">Wstaw datę dla dnia projektowego: </span></td><td style="border: 1px solid #676767"><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Width="249px" style="margin-right:3px;"></asp:TextBox></td><td style="border: 1px solid #676767"> format (2012-10-30)</td></tr>
    <tr><td style="border: 1px solid #676767; width:200px;"><span style="color:#FF0000; font-weight:bold;">Wstaw procent zaangarzowania: </span></td><td style="border: 1px solid #676767"><asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" Width="273px"></asp:DropDownList></td><td  style="border: 1px solid #676767"> od (1/8..8/8)</td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="3" style="border: 1px solid #676767;"><asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Dodaj pojedyńczy dzień projektowy" onclick="Button2_Click" Width="600px" /></td></tr>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added  this code, and it worked ;)

`<Triggers>
<asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="Button6" />
</Triggers>`